# MySql service nor working in WAMP

Tags: mysql, wampserver

I have installed WAMP server in my PC.When i installed all services are worked properly.On next day i started WAMP mysql service alone not working.I tried all the possibilities,the icon like half yellow and half white.i reinstalled the WAMP the mysql is working fine on that day only next day it wont work.Please help me...

Mysql latest log:

```
090814 13:16:14 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
090814 13:16:14  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
090814 13:16:16  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 0 46409
090814 13:16:16 [Warning] Forcing shutdown of 1 plugins
090814 13:16:16 [Note] wampmysqld: Shutdown complete
```

Please suggest to solve this.Advance thanks to all.....

Answer (score 0):

looks like the mysql server is crashing. you should change the server to use the debug version of mysql so it can write a crash dump.